# Does Blender bloat unnecessarily the Windows Registry?

Tags: performance, windows, optimization

According to Revo Uninstaller, Blender adds more than 4400 registry keys to the Windows Registry. They are almost all spread in Registry folder:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\[your user string]\Components
```

Assuming that the Windows Registry is kind of a highway (database) where system and user applications will eventually want to **quickly** store and share data, unnecessarily growing it will impact other applications performance on accessing, not to mention the impact on registry backups that Windows makes periodically.

Next follows an old opinion of Jeff Atwood about using registry as a storage room (source: [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/was-the-windows-registry-a-good-idea/)):

> a trash heap of miscellaneous junk settings for every rinky-dink application on the planet

Many of the 4400+ entries that Blender stores in Registry, if not all, are references to Python scripts, that I strongly doubt they really need to be stored in a **system wide** database, instead of a local configuration folder.

Comment: The part of the registry that you've listed contains keys of all installers, not just by Blender. It certainly does not add thousands of keys.

Comment: After exporting the mentioned registry branch, and counting "Blender" folder references with Notepad+, the exact number results 4322 entries. The difference with 4400 is explained with other registry entries detected by Revo Uninstaller in other branches.

Comment: Not every entry you'll find is created by Blender's installer, but the OS itself. You'll find similar number of entries for every other software, when you're simply searching for the name. Either way Blender does not abuse the registry, it uses a simple WiX based installer. You shouldn't purge registry entries unless you absolutely know what you're doing, because they are very likely needed.

Comment: I use Revo Uninstaller to install applications and track with precision registry and file system changes. Certainly all applications make changes, but they use to keep a low level (except for large / highly integrated apps, i.e. Visual Studio). Blender's 4000+ changes reached the red alert level, it's not usual. Of course I won't delete anything nor recommend it! This question was more like a wink for Blender developers, in order to not bloat Registry and keep Blender being the great, fast and clean tool it really is.

Comment: If you want to give developers feedback, then you can create a post on https://devtalk.blender.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are unsure about entrys in the registry and want to keep your system clean, you can take the portable version.
Extract to a folder of your choice and pin to startmenu or what ever.

I personally dont use Blender installer at all, i use the portable every time and when there is a new build i override the folder content and have the new version.
If you have multiple versions you can have different folders.

[image]

Comment: Great answer! The perfect one would be (from the developers) "We'll remove junk entries in the next version". But for now, this is the best.